# Setting projection to a geotiff file when it's shown as Unknown

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff

I have a geotiff file that has no CRS in the metadata  but I know that the CRS of the raster is WGS 84 UTM 22 N.
How can I modify the geotiff file to have the CRS  WGS 84 UTM 22 N in the metadata.

Best Regards

Comment: what kind of tools you want to use? And manually or by scripting?

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways depending on the software you use and you want to do it manually or scripting..

With ArcGIS it's simply in Arc Catalog clicking on the dataset with right button to access Properties- At the place of Sp.Reference you can edit it and set to your desired one (but it's just when you really know that the coordinates and extent of ur data is from that coordinate system, but it just wasn't set).
More explained in Esri [help.](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?id=205&pid=198&topicname=Specifying%20a%20coordinate%20system&)

With open source GDAL you can use the tool called: [GDAL warp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html)

Comment: OK thanks I've used Arcgis and that did the Job :-)

Comment: Hi @Thomas - welcome to GIS.stackexchange! If this answer worked for you, you should select it as 'correct' by selecting the check-mark just below the score count at the top of the answer. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for background on how voting and acceptance work.